# Error generando libreria Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-cli

Al tratar de generar la librería importando los módulos de /src/app/... Me devuelve el siguiente error

```
BUILD ERROR
error TS6059: File 'C:/ruta/fuera/de/la/libreria/fichero.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'C:\ruta\de\la\libreria\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

Lo curioso es que solo me pasa con los módulos que yo he programado, si por ejemplo importo una librería, no me da ningún error.

```
import { NzDrawerRef } from 'ng-zorro-antd';
```

Tras investigar, he buscado y he visto que hay que meter en el fichero `tsconfig.lib.json` de la librería el parámetro `rootDir` o bien `rootDirs`, pero los pongo y no me cambia nada.

La configuración del fichero tsconfig.lib.json es

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src",
      "./../../src/app/modules/modulo/a/importar"
    ],
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": false,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizas un fichero que no está dentro del directorio de tu proyecto? Lo que entiendo, es que estas importando un fichero dentro de tu librería, pero este fichero no se encuentra en el directorio de la librería, no?

Comment: Porque necesito empaquetar módulos de la aplicación, es decir la librería necesita de algunos componentes, módulos, etc. Que están en la carpeta src del proyecto